# Why the Visual Force page request is called twice when used window.open JS from LWC?

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

The community users can render the VF page as a PDF and record this action in the custom object as a log record when they click the button to generate the PDF from the LWC on the community page (digital experience page).

When a user clicks the button the LWC opens another tab in the browser and a PDF is generated.
However, the problem is that two records are created on the custom object LogPDF__c.
Also, when I debug the issue I can see two separate debug logs for a user action.

The LWC has a button:

```
<button onclick={generatePDF}>
    Generate PDF
</button>
```

the function on LWC

```
generatePDF() {
        const urlPDF = 'https://power-business-3760-dev-ed.scratch.my.site.com/apex/testVFPageRenderAsPDF';

        console.log('const url pdf ', urlPDF);
        window.open(urlPDF, '_blank');
    }
```

Visual force page

```
<apex:page controller="TestVFPageRenderAsPDFController" renderAs="pdf" action="{!createVFPDFLog}">
    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
    <h1>Congratulations</h1>
    This is your new Page
    <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

Controller for Visual Force page

```
public with sharing class TestVFPageRenderAsPDFController {
    public TestVFPageRenderAsPDFController() {
        System.debug('xxx constructor');
    }

    public void createVFPDFLog() {
        System.debug('xxx createVFPDFLog');
        LogPDF__c logPDF = new LogPDF__c();
        insert logPDF;
    }
}
```

I have checked the debug logs, and the debug logs are separate transactions.
[Two debugs logs created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqjMd.png)

I have checked the problem in different browsers and the issue is only seen on the Edge browser.
In Chrome the debug logs and LogPDF record is created one time.

I checked the settings of the browser and couldn't find anything useful and related to my issue.

I suspect it might be something related with calling that VF page from the community page.
When I created the LWC with a button and called that from the salesforce org, it generated the PDF and created the log record only one time.

I would like to have only one log record created on the LogPDF custom object per one Generate PDF pressed button.